# Settle first value from database to bottom in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

[I want to display data as a tertis block game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxtMP.png)

Current display:

```
-0.1
+0.22
-0.33
-0.4
```

Expected display:

```
-0.4
-0.33
+0.22
-0.1
```

I have tried using `array_reverse` and `array_unshift`. But no satisfying result.

This is the code:

```
$result="select x1,y1,angle1 from csv_data ORDER BY x1 "; //query on database 
$output=mysqli_query($con,$result); //no.of rows 
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($output); //fetching all data 
$row=mysqli_fetch_all($output,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

for($i=0;$i<$rowcount;$i++) {
    echo $row[$i]['x1']."\t".$row[$i]['y1']."\t".$row[$i]['angle1']."<br>"; 
    ob_flush();
    flush(); 
    sleep($delay);
}
```

I want to display last updated value at top and first read value to settle at bottom of page

Comment: `ORDER BY column_name DESC`

Comment: I want to display data as a tertis block game

Comment: Can you please share the code in which you create this output?

Comment: for($i=0;$i<$rowcount;$i++)
{
    echo $row[$i]['x1']."\t".$row[$i]['y1']."\t".$row[$i]['angle1']."<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep($delay);
}

Comment: show database query

Comment: `ORDER BY <column name>+0 DESC`

Comment: you can get data from query in `DESC` order

Comment: $result="select x1,y1,angle1 from csv_data  ORDER BY x1 DESC ";
//query on database
$output=mysqli_query($con,$result);
//no.of rows
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($output);
//fetching all data
$row=mysqli_fetch_all($output,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: I want to display last updated value at top and first read value to settle at bottom of page

Comment: the data is sensor data.

Comment: [Reverse your string after using explode](https://eval.in/1054892)

Comment: If that was your try then try this `select x1,y1,angle1 from csv_data`

Comment: I want the data to display as FIRST IN manner. like as block game. append the latest value on top of previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a manual swap?

```
// Get your result
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//Then do a manual swap
$tmp = $arr[0];
$arr[0] = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
$arr[count($arr) - 1] = $tmp;
```

Your question isn't clear, are you refering to this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for ($i = $rowcount-1; $i>=0; $i--) { 
   ...
}
```

:D

Comment: This code does the same as array_reverse, order by desc.